# Mono Android Monodroid Native Library DllNotFoundException

Tags: xamarin.android

I am attempting to get a Native C/C++ library working with Monodroid in the emulator, using DllImport. I am developing mainly in Windows/Visual Studio 2010.

I have built a native C/C++ library (ZeroMQ) using the Android NDK tools, to both x86 and armeabi platforms, using a Ubuntu virtual machine. Is this correct - x86 for emulator and armeabi for the real device? (This is certainly the case on the iPhone/MonoTouch - though in that case statically linked libzmq.a file and DllImport __Internal)

I have added the x86 version of libzmq.so to my MonoDroid project under the directory structure lib\x86\libzmq.so

When I first attempted to build/deploy to the simulator, I got an error 'cannot determine abi type', so I've added x86 to the AndroidNativeLibrary Include="lib\x86\libzmq.so"> project item group. This then deployed.

I have a DllImport for the function to call [DllImport("libzmq"

I've tried libzmq.so, lib/x86/libzmq, lib/x86/libzmq.so etc, but then I call the DllImported method (running in the emulator), I always get a DllNotFoundException.

Can anyone give me some direction?

EDIT: After reading another support answer which states that the emulator uses armeabi .so libraries, I have removed the x86/libzmq and added my lib/armeabi/libzmq.so as an AndroidNativeLibrary. I also removed the project file Abi entry, and indeed the project built and deployed fine.

However, I *still* get a DllNotFoundException when I try to call a DllImported function. Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it working! For whatever reason, ZeroMQ doesn't build correctly using the current/latest NDK r7. The instructions at http://www.zeromq.org/build:android use NDK r6. I also downloaded an old version of the NDK r5b (it was the easiest old version to find a download for), and rebuilt ZeroMQ using it. Result, it now works on emulator and phone!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any immediate ideas why it isn't working for you; `[DllImport("zmq")]` should work.

The [SanityTests sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SanityTests) exercises the `DllImport` attribute.

- The `DllImport`: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SanityTests/Hello.cs#L240
- The `Android.mk` to build `libfoo.so`: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SanityTests/jni/Android.mk
- Building `libfoo.so` by calling `ndk-build`: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SanityTests/SanityTests.csproj#L82
- Including `libfoo.so` into the `.apk`: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SanityTests/SanityTests.csproj#L96

Answer (score 0):

*(This is a repeat of my reply to your email in the ZeroMQ mailing list).*

This error could be caused by using an incorrect platform target in your Mono project. I'm not sure if Mono/MonoDevelop supports this, but you probably need to create an ARM platform target, as opposed to x86/x64/Any CPU.

You would experience the same errors if you tried to do P/Invoke interop between an x64-targeted assembly with an x86 native library or vice-versa.

If you're using the clrzmq bindings for bridging Mono and libzmq, you will need to create a new platform target for ARM and rebuild the bindings. The solution only defines x86 and x64 platform targets currently.