# ZeroMQ build for Android emulator x86

Tags: android, xamarin, zeromq

I build zeroMQ [under this instruction](http://zeromq.org/build%3aandroid).
I create Xamarin project for android, add from nuget clrzmq package and put libzmq.so file to folders
libs->armeabi
libs->armeabi-v7a
libs->x86

When I debug application on real device. It seems to be working.
But when I run application on Android emulatior x86 (Genymotion).
I catch DllNotFoundException
and see message in device log 
libzmq not found.

I try to build with x86 version of library as

--host=i686-linux-android

How can I build zeromq for android-x86 architecture?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, see

[Mono Android Monodroid Native Library DllNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812145/mono-android-monodroid-native-library-dllnotfoundexception/8873795#8873795)

My problem came down to the version of the NDK I used - an older version seemed to work better.

Edit:

It's a long time since I built the Android version of ZeroMQ, but I finally found the Ubuntu virtual machine I used to build it, and found the shell history for when I built it:

`623  pwd
  624  cd zeromq-2.1.11/
  625  make clean
  626  ./configure --target=x86 --host=x86 LDFLAGS="-L/opt/android-root/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/android-root/include" --prefix=/opt/android-root
  627  ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/opt/android-root/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/android-root/include" --prefix=/opt/android-root
  628  ./configure --target=x86 LDFLAGS="-L/opt/android-root/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/android-root/include" --prefix=/opt/android-root
  629  which diff
  630  cp config.status config.status.x86
  631  ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/opt/android-root/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/android-root/include" --prefix=/opt/android-root
  632  diff config.status config.status.x86
  633  ./configure --target=x86 --host=x86 LDFLAGS="-L/opt/android-root/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/android-root/include" --prefix=/opt/android-root
  634  ./configure --host=x86 LDFLAGS="-L/opt/android-root/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/android-root/include" --prefix=/opt/android-root
  635  ./configure --target=x86 LDFLAGS="-L/opt/android-root/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/android-root/include" --prefix=/opt/android-root
  636  make
  637  sudo make install`

`1174  sudo android-ndk-r5b/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-5 --install-dir=/opt/android-toolchain
 1175  cd /opt
 1176  ls
 1177  ls -l
 1178  ls
 1179  export PATH=/opt/android-toolchain/bin:$PATH
 1180  cd 
 1181  cd e2fsprogs/
 1182  ./configure -target=arm-linux-androideabi -host=arm-linux-androideabi -prefix=/opt/android-root
 1183  make clean
 1184  make
 1185  make clean
 1186  cd lib
 1187  cd uuid/
 1188  make
 1189  sudo make install
 1190  cd
 1191  cd zeromq-2.1.11/
 1192  ./configure -target=arm-linux-androideabi -host=arm-linux-androideabi LDFLAGS="-L/opt/android-root/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/android-root/include" -prefix=/opt/android-root
 1193  make clean
 1194  make
 1195  sudo make install`

As seen above, I used the r5b version of the NDK, and built ZeroMQ 2.1.11. I also remember that UUID needed to be built and used for ZeroMQ 2, but I think this has chaged in ZeroMQ 3.

I can't remember which version of the x86 worked unfortunately, but it may give you a starting point.

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you tell me more specifically? What exactly flags need to perform with ./configure? I try to Use Ndk 9 and and do everything in accordance with the instructions on the site (http://zeromq.org/build%3aandroid). Please, if not difficult show a sample script that build the correct library. Thanks!

Comment: It is also very strange that during the existence of the library no one has described the scenario of its use with Xamarin in documentation or any blogs article. Whatever it was, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At first, make sure you have created correct standalone tool chain for x86, try to build ZeroMQ for x86 according to below article:

Compiling ZeroMQ library for Android* Applications on Intel® x86 Platforms 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/compiling-zeromq-library-for-android-applications-on-intel-x86-platforms